# dreamweaver ignores css files

Tags: css, dreamweaver

```
<link href="/qbaccounting.ca/_css/qba_main.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/qbaccounting.ca/_css/qba_content.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

here is my css link in my dreamweaver web page. when i see it in drw, it looks good, text centered, color white, nice background, logo image, but when i upload it to the server it is as if there is no css file at all, no image, and text half centered, half not.
tried deleting index and css files, copied instead of put, nothing works. 
what to do?

Comment: Don't use Dreamweaver :-) Post a link..

Comment: Be aware that starting your link with the "/" puts in on the root. Use "./" for relative linking.

Comment: Thanks, fat fingers, bracket is there.

Answer (score 1):

Your second link tag is missing the closing >

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/qba_content.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/qba_main.css">. moved the syntax around. now it works. dont exactly understand why, but i am happy to work on improving the page, rather than trying to make it work. thanks for the suggestions. missing > was due to fat fingers in copying and pasting.